# Sign in without using UI Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress, ui-automation

I am trying to log in without using the UI.
After inspecting to page while logging in I can see the page form data takes:

```
Authenticity_token: someToken
user[email]: someEmail
user[password]: somePassword
user[remember_me]: 0
commit: Sign in
```

How do I sign in without using the UI ? This is what I have, but when running this Im getting

> 422: Unprocessable Entity

```
    it('logs in without UI', function() {

    const email = 'someEmail'
    const password = 'somePassword'

    cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "someUrl",
        form: true,
        body: {
            email,
            password,
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Check if `email` should be named `username`.

Comment: When changing email to username I am getting the same `422: Unprocessable Entity` error @Fody